# Arquillian with tomcat7 running into Java Heap Space problems, only on linux

Tags: linux, testing, tomcat7, heap-memory, jboss-arquillian

we are running arquillian with tomcat 7...
With the MAC from my colleague the test works fine, but at my linux computer (we both have 8gb ram) it failes with:

```
FATAL: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

when i start my test, i see in the stack this line:

> 14:05:56.482 INFO - Starting Tomcat with: [java,
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8089, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Xmx512m, -XX:MaxPermSize=128m, -classpath, /home/user/apache-tomcat-testing/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/user/apache-tomcat-testing/bin/tomcat-juli.jar,
>   -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/user/apache-tomcat-testing/endorsed, -Dcatalina.base=/home/user/apache-tomcat-testing, -Dcatalina.home=/home/user/apache-tomcat-testing, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/user/apache-tomcat-testing/temp, org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap, -config,
>   /home/user/apache-tomcat-testing/conf/server.xml, start]

i tried to edit the `bin/catalina.sh` with

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

but it still has the `xmx=512m` in the stack.
i also added in the `pom.xml` the `<argLine>-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m</argLine>` for `failsafe-maven-plugin` and for the `maven-surefire-plugin` but still the same error...

Where is the right place to change the xmx for the arquillian testing?

thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you're using the Arquillian managed Tomcat 7 container. Use the `javaVmArguments` property in arquillian.xml to specify the `Xmx` values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <container qualifier="tomcat" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="catalinaHome">${CATALINA_HOME:target/apache-tomcat-7.0.20}</property>
            <property name="javaVmArguments">-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m</property>
            <property name="jmxPort">8089</property>
            <property name="bindHttpPort">8080</property>
            <property name="user">manager</property>
            <property name="pass">password</property>
            <property name="serverConfig">server.xml</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

The complete reference to the properties supported for the managed Tomcat 7 container is in the [Arquillian Confluence wiki](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Tomcat+7.0+-+Managed).

Comment: how a bout the PermGen space problem with Maven and arquillian on managed tomcats. Will this solve the PermGen space problem also, or not?

Comment: @Yashar No, set the `MaxPermSize` and `PermSize` arguments for perm gen issues. And allow Arquillian to restart Tomcat on after `n` deployments. There is a configuration property for the latter.

Comment: The javaVmArguments option also works for Wildfly 8.1.0. although I could not find the corresponding documentation.